# Determine whether the data with initial data is changed or not in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have to compare updated data with initially loaded data in AngularJS. I tried the following way but I didn't get updated one.

```
$http.get('users').then(function (resp) {
    $scope.items = resp.data.items;
    $scope.oitems = resp.data.items;

});
```

Here `$scope.items` can be updated in form,

```
$scope.doneEditing = function () {

    if (!angular.equals($scope.items, $scope.oitems)) {
        alert('changed');
    }
  }
```

In my way I cannot track the changes in initial data. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do like

```
$scope.items = resp.data.items;
$scope.oitems = resp.data.items;
```

`$scope.items` and `$scope.oitems` are pointed to same object in the memory. because of that after u  change a `$scope.item` you will have the same changed object in `$scope.oitems`.

what you need is create a separate object for `$scope.oitems` with `initial` values of `$scope.items` to do that you can use `angular.copy();`

**solution**

```
$http.get('users').then(function (resp) {
    $scope.items = resp.data.items;
    $scope.oitems = angular.copy($scope.items);
});


$scope.doneEditing = function () {
    if (!angular.equals($scope.items, $scope.oitems )) {
        alert('changed');
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your code ..but always getting `changed` even though i not updated any data

Comment: could u please post ur controller and the view